# iPhone MKMapView force callout bubble

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, callouts

Is it possible to force the call out bubble to be open all the time? I tried putting the following code in didAddAnnotionViews:

```
for (id<MKAnnotation> currentAnnotation in mapView.annotations) {       
    [mapView selectAnnotation:currentAnnotation animated:NO];
}
```

Which works, however, when I single tap the MKMapView the bubble disappear. I want to avoid this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is. The solution is probably to make your pin design *look* like your callout. Would that help ?

Comment: I agree with Andiih. I had a similar problem and got around it using this method. Get the center point of the selected annotation then build and add the appropriate subview setting it's center+offset to align them up correctly.